# compress similar rows in oracle/SQL

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to consider a table design in oracle/SQL where many rows in a database are related to each other and will always be queried together but do contain different information (although many of the columns will contain similar information between the similar rows)

In that sense, it seems to me that it would be more efficient to somehow compress several rows into a single row in Oracle that contains a single common recordID and is always stored together on disk since they are always inserted, deleted, queried and extracted together.  For this type of table, is there some sort of Row Compression that can be used so that these related rows aren't treated as individual rows for better performance?

Updated:  An example would be as follows

```
Field1  Field2  Field3
1       1       A
1       2       B
1       3       C
2       4       D
2       5       E
```

In this example, I would always insert and query the first three rows together (because they share Field1 values).  They are separate pieces of data, but they are never separated from each other.  Is there some way to insert, store, index and extract them as a group while keeping them as separate data rows?

Comment: Can you provide some simple examples? It almost sounds like you are trying to put everything in a single table when it should perhaps be in several smaller tables. To get "everything in one place" you may use views (or perhaps materialized views) depending on the situation.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original post with an example.  It's not really something appropriate to create a subtable though, since they are just pieces of random data that generally doesn't repeat.   The subtables would effectively be the same size as the original table I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Exadata then you can go for Exadata Hybrid Columnar Compression.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/exadata/ehcc-twp-131254.pdf

If you are not on Exadata you can still use OLTP compression.

http://allthingsoracle.com/compression-in-oracle-part-3-oltp-compression/

Comment: I don't think the OP meant "compression" in the standard technical sense... did you read his question?

Comment: Yes, I read the question and felt that the suggested compression techniques would help in achieving the required objective to a certain extent.